# How to create multi-dimensional structure array in python using dictionary

Tags: dictionary, structure

Is there a way to form a dictionary in python which opens and appears like the following picture in MATLAB (in structure format)? The saving was done using hdf5storage.savemat.

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

I would convert the dictionary into a pandas data frame:

```
import pandas as pd 
data = [{'area': 'new-hills', 'rainfall': 100, 'temperature': 20}, 
         {'area': 'cape-town',  'rainfall': 70, 'temperature': 25}, 
         {'area': 'mumbai',  'rainfall': 200,  'temperature': 39 }] 
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
```

Many IDEs (e.g. PyCharm) provide visualization options for data frames.
Lazloo